# Is Ramda ifElse an effective pattern if it abstracts a ternary operation

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ternary-operator, ramda.js

Risky question to be opinionated. I'm working on a project with Ramda.js. And I see many `ifElse` calls throughout the code.

```
const getEvent = R.ifElse(
  fireable,
  R.always(sendAnalyticsEvent),
  R.always(R.always(undefined))
);
```

### Is this really worth the effort to wrap logic in a functional conditional like this? Is there a benefit?

If ultimately Ramda just abstracts a ternary operation and we return undefined on false match.

Ramdas ifElse

```
var ifElse = _curry3(function ifElse(condition, onTrue, onFalse) {
  return curryN(Math.max(condition.length, onTrue.length, onFalse.length),
    function _ifElse() {
      return condition.apply(this, arguments) ? onTrue.apply(this, arguments) : onFalse.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  );
});
export default ifElse;
```

This seems like an anitpattern in the FP world, always returning undefined or in some cases null

`R.ifElse(hasUrl, promptToShare, R.always(null))`

Regardless of the questionable return of undefined, wouldn't using ternary operators be more idiomatic to a javascript community?

`hasUrl(urlObject) ? promptToShare() : null`

This seems more succinct and legible to me, I want to refactor. But this could be due to my naivety of the FP world.

Comment: You can partially apply/curry a function. You cannot partially apply operators in JS.

Comment: You also can't compose them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several points (disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author):

- Far too often, you're right.  Point-free code is overused when new users pick up FP in Javascript.  I generally suggest that it's only useful when it improves readability.
- An `ifElse` invocation is not equivalent to a Javascript conditional expression (ternary.)  It can be equivalent to a lambda function that returns the value of a ternary, however.  That is, the example would be more like `(urlObject) => hasUrl(urlObject) ? promptToShare(urlObject) : null`.  At this point, the `ifElse` is at least possibly more readable.  This brings us to the points from the comments about partial application/currying
- There is little reason I can see to use `ifElse` with functions that have different signatures.  That is, if `promptToShare` takes no arguments, then it probably doesn't belong in a call to `ifElse`.
- That `getEvent` function looks quite bizarre.  Given that it uses a name like `sendAnalyticsEvent`, I'm guessing that it creates some side-effect.  And the other branch is a no-op.  While the Ramda team doesn't really care how you use the library, this is not the sort of function we envision users creating with it.
- I've seen other odd calls to `ifElse` passing identity for one of the branch functions.  Those should presumably be replaced with `when` or `unless`, which would certainly be more semantic.

So I agree that your example does not need `ifElse` at all.  But `ifElse` and its peers `when` and `unless` do have their places.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer Scott. I'll take a look at the `when` function. Thats interesting to note with function signatures that differ `ifElse` may not be suitable. I'll keep that in mind.